# Internal VHost Naming Convention for Mac LAN

Tags: macos, nginx, dns, vhosts

I'm looking for a way to name `vhost` test/production internal websites on my workstation.  I have around 10 internal websites that I want to access on both internal computers and mobile devices.  Back to that later.

My workstation is a `Mac` running `nginx`.  I've been using `*.local` but the `.local` nomenclature is reserved for Bonjour.

I have an internal `DNS server` that I can plug with records for internal resolution.  I do own a minimum of one `FQDN` that points to me externally, but I can only assume that this can be managed internally.

How can I name my `vhosts` so I can make everything visible on the `LAN`by using my internal `DNS server`?  **machinename.example.com** which points to my workstation, only brings visitors to the workstation, and obviously goes to the default `nginx` server directive, which doesn't help at all.  I need `vhost` names.

I am using static internal IPs for various machines that are hosting services.

Comment: Configure machinename.example.com vhosts in your nginx?

Comment: @DusanBajic As what?  They are *.local at the moment.  They all can't be machinename.example.com.

Comment: Oh, you are looking for name suggestion, not the technical solution? Well, maybe `website1.machinename.example.com`, `website2.machinename.example.com`, .. `websiteN.machinename.example.com`?

Comment: There you go.  Just what I was looking for.  I will give that a try.  That appears to be the technical solution right there.